# Macos Vscode Kubernetes extention unable to start minikube error - dyld Symbol not found

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Installed docker , minikube , helm from brew.

Started docker , minikube

Vscode kubernetes plugin was unable to locate kubectl and giving error
`dyld: Symbol not found:`

Answer (score 0):

added user settings for vscode kubernetes plugin , pointing to local install location

```
 "vs-kubernetes": {   
        "vs-kubernetes.kubectl-path": "/usr/local/bin/kubectl",
        "vscode-kubernetes.minikube-path": "/usr/local/bin/minikube",
        "vscode-kubernetes.kubectl-path": "/usr/local/bin/kubectl",
        "vs-kubernetes.helm-path": "/usr/local/bin/helm"
}
```